# What's the difference between indicative summarization and informative summarization?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text-processing, summarization

I have trouble in distinguishing between indicative summarization and informative summarization. Can you give me a clear example to show the difference between them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [hovy&lin1998](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/cyl/tipster-proc-hovy-lin-final.pdf):

> An indicative
>   summary provides merely an indication of the
>   principal subject matter or domain of the input text(s)
>   without including its contents. After reading an
>   informative summary, one can explain what the input
>   text was about, but not necessarily what was
>   contained in it. An informative summary reflects
>   (some of) the content, and allows one to describe
>   (parts of) what was in the input text.

**Informative summary:** It contains the informative part of the original text. After reading it, you can tell what are the main ideas in the original document. you can find informative summaries in reasearch articles where the author tries to present the essentiel of its reasearch.

**Indicative summary:** It doesn't contain informative content; it contains only metadata (a description of the document). It is used to inform the reader about the scope of the document and such to help help them decide whether or not to consult the original document. You can find such type of summaries, for example, on the verso of the title page of books and reports.

Following [newworldencyclopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Abstract_(summary)):

**Informative content:** are material contents of the document, which includes conclusions, suggestions, and recommendations.

**Metadata:** is a description of what kind of information it is, which includes the purpose, scope, and research methodology.